# rolled back app_controller.php, cakephp still whitescreening

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

Thanks in advance.  I'm confused.  I made changes to app_controller.php in CakePHP and then rolled it back to what I know is a good copy after whitescreening.  I am still getting the white screen of death even so.  Can't figure out what to look for here...

I checked the logs and there is no useful info.

Kris

Answer (score 1):

Check your config/core.php file. Set the debug value back to 1 in order to display your errors. White screens usually happen to prevent your users from seeing errors.

If this is already on a live server, deleting cache can also be helpful. Visit your app/tmp folder and clean it out. Refresh.

Comment: Hi, thanks, which folders in tmp do I want to delete?  All of them?  Interestingly, I've tried setting debug to 1 in this app (inherited) and it breaks a lot of functionality.  My app did come back after about 5 minutes tho so I guess it was the cache...will start clearing that if I am confident I am only deleting the right folders.

Comment: If possible, delete just the content of the folders under tmp/cache. If you delete the folders themselves, you will have to recreate the exact same folders and then CHMOD them all to 777, to make sure they're writable by Cake. Hope that helps!

Comment: Bear in mind that you should not delete the folders it self, but the files in them. I think that the folders in /app/tmp are not recreated after the deletion and you could have problems in the future if you do that.